# ZedGraph C# bar chart - how to check which bar was clicked by mouse?

Tags: c#, zedgraph

I am using ZedGraph to draw my plots in C#. I need to know which bar (in bar chart) was clicked by a mouse. How can I do that? Is there any way to get a bar by a point and for example change bar`s color?

Answer (score 4):

Use `MouseClick` event and find the X and Y coordinates of the point where you clicked:

```
    zg1.MouseClick+=new MouseEventHandler(zg1_MouseClick3);



    private void zg1_MouseClick3(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        PointF pt = (PointF)e.Location;
        double x,y;
        ((ZedGraphControl)sender).MasterPane[0].ReverseTransform(pt, out x, out y);

        // Do something with X and Y
    }
```

Note, that I assumed we are operating on first pane (index 0) but if it is not your case, then you'll have to find which pane was clicked (see this [example](http://zedgraph.org/wiki/index.php?title=Edit_Points_by_Dragging_the_Mouse)).

When you have X and Y position you should easily be able to guess which bar was clicked and do whatever you need with that information.

Comment: Wow, I used to compute this using an affine transformation of `pt` based on `pane.X/YAxisScale` and `pane.Chart.Rect`; ReverseTransform reduces my 6 lines into one! Btw you can access the graph pane via `ZedGraphControl.GraphPane`, and to avoid casting the sender you can register to `ZedGraphControl.MouseDown/UpEvent` whose delegate takes a `ZedGraphControl` as 1st parameter.